# Pandas : Find rows of a Dataframe that are not in another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas Dataframe `df1` and `df2` where `df2` is a part of `df1` and I want to create a Dataframe `df3`, which contains all the rows from `df1` that are not in `df2`.

Here is an example :

```
print(df1)

>>
+---------+
|       ID|
+---------+
|      AAA|
|      DDD|
|      BBB|
|      CCC|
|      EEE|
|      FFF|
+---------+

print(df2)

>>
+---------+
|       ID|
+---------+
|      AAA|
|      EEE|
|      FFF|
+---------+

print(df3)

>>
+---------+
|       ID|
+---------+
|      DDD|
|      BBB|
|      CCC|
+---------+
```

Note:

- My DataFrame might have multiple columns, but the matching must be done on the `ID` column only.

Answer (score 6):

```
df3 = df1.loc[~df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])].copy()
```

Comment: Can you add a little detail to what the above like what the code do?